# How to solve this linker error

Tags: linker, libtool

When I make a plasma simulation project, the linker reports this error:

```
../libpsc/.libs/libpsc.a(push_part_1vb_mix.o):(.rodata+0x38): undefined reference to `psc_push_particles_1vb_ps2_ops'
```

Actually, the problem is obvious. The c file ../libpsc/FOLDER_A/push_part_1vb_mix.c (call it A.c) refers to a

```
struct psc_push_particles_ops psc_push_particles_1vb_ps2_ops = { //definition
```

defined in ../libpsc/FOLDER_B/psc_push_particles_ps.c (call it B.c). The A.c includes a header file (located in ../include/) which contains

```
extern struct psc_push_particles_ops psc_push_particles_1vb_ps2_ops;
```

However, the linker report this error anyway. So how can I fix this problem? Is this caused by the makefile? I don't know how the linker solves references and any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `psc_push_particles_1vb_ps2_ops` in a conditional in `B.c`?  It could be conditioned out.  Is `B.c` getting added to the `libpsc.a` library or linked to whatever the final binary is?

Comment: @ldav1s Nope, there is no condition proceeding that struct. I think the problem is in Makefile. B.c didn't get compiled into B.o. Is this the problem?

Comment: If `B.c` isn't compiled into `B.o`, then there's no way for `B.o` to be added to a library or linked to some other binary.  So yes, that's a problem.